# UiViewController which supports Landscape Orientation puts other Views in Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I searched now for a day an did not find a proper solution.
My app consists of a Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Controllers inside.
I want all screens only Portrait, but just one sub view been Landscape.

And it works to get there, but when I return from the subview staying in landscape orientation physically, the parent also is presented as landscape, despite the fact that I only permit .portrait ind the controller.

I already did:

```
extension UITabBarController {
   override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
      get {
          if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
              return visibleVC.shouldAutorotate
          }
          return super.shouldAutorotate
      }
   }

   override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
       get {
           if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
               return visibleVC.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
           }
           return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
       }
   }

   override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      // your custom logic for rotation of selected tab
         get {
               if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
                   return visibleVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations
               }
               return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
           }
   }
}

extension UINavigationController {
   override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
       get {
           if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
               return visibleVC.shouldAutorotate
           }
           return super.shouldAutorotate
       }
   }

   override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
       get {
           if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
               return visibleVC.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
           }
           return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
       }
   }

   override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
       get {
           if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
               return visibleVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations
           }
           return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
       }
   }
}
```

and in the parent controller:

```
  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
      return true
   }

   override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
        return .portrait
   }

   override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
      return .portrait
   }
```

When I turn the device then to Portrait the View is again displayed in Portrait, but I want that to happen immediately after the dismissal of the child in landscape, even if I don't turn the device.

Any ideas anybody?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your landscape View controller add this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myOrientation = .landscapeRight
}
```

and ViewWillDisappear add this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myOrientation = .portrait
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```

In appDeledate add this line

```
var window: UIWindow?
var myOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your proposal works very well! Thanks again.